# Default EditorTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine

I'm trying to just ever so slightly tweak the default `EditorTemplate` for a `SelectList`. Is there somewhere where I can find the source for all the default `EditorTemplates` (i.e so I have a base reference to work off of).

I've had a peek on the asp.net mvc source page and cannot find the templates listed in their source code (although I am most likely missing it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default EditorTemplate for a SelectList is actually just this method:
[System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal()](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs)

So it is not implemented as a .cshtml template at all.  Instead it builds up the markup in C# using a TagBuilder.  You could take this implementation as a starting point for your own C# method, or else port it into the equivalent razor syntax.